# ctypes behaving strangely in Python interpreter

Tags: python, ctypes

I am having a funny issue with ctypes; while it seems to work in regular python scripts, when I use it in the interpreter with printf() it prints the length of the string after the string itself. A demo:

```
Python 2.6.5 (r265:79063, Apr 16 2010, 13:09:56) 
[GCC 4.4.3] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from ctypes import *
>>> libc = CDLL("libc.so.6")
>>> libc.printf("Test")
Test4
>>> int = 55
>>> libc.printf("Test %d", int)
Test 557
>>> int = c_int(55)
>>> libc.printf("Test %d", int)
Test 557
```

Does anyone know why this happens?

Comment: Just a note - while `int` isn't a reserved word, it is in fact a built-in attribute.  You shouldn't get in the habit of assigning references to it.

Comment: I know, but this is just a small interpreter test.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From the printf(3) man page:

> Upon  successful  return,  these  functions  return  the  number of characters printed (not including the trailing `’\0’` used to end output to strings).

The python interpreter is displaying the return code of `printf()` after you call it. Since you don't have a newline `\n` at the end of your strings the length is getting printed immediately after the printout. Note that this won't happen in a script, only when you use python interactively.

You could hide this with an assignment:

```
ret = libc.printf("Test\n")
```

Comment: Just curious, is it dangerous to pass a python str into a function expecting char*?

Comment: Yes, if the function expects to modify the content of the string.  Python strings are immutable.  ctypes has a create_string_buffer() function to create character arrays that can be modified.